# Disable single checkbox in a ListView with checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, checkbox

I have a ListView with checkboxes:

```
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.CheckBoxes = true;

        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("ONE");
        ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("TWO");
        ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("THREE");

        listView1.Items.Add(item1);
        listView1.Items.Add(item2);
        listView1.Items.Add(item3);
```

I would like to disable only the second checkbox, is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you disable an item in listview control in .net 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472172/how-do-you-disable-an-item-in-listview-control-in-net-3-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do that with owner drawing using the **DrawItem** event. In the event handler, draw a rectangle filled with **SystemColors.Window** over the check box to hide it.

I have also implemented check box hiding in 3rd party control [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express). Items have a boolean property named **AllowShowCheckBox** which you can set to false on every item separately. It also supports three-state check boxes.