# Disabling checkbox for an item in listview control

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, checkbox

I have `Checkboxes` in my `ListView` control and set to True.
Further, I add items in the `ListView` one by one. It is not bound to a `DataSet` / `DataTable`.

At time, I am adding items with `Checkbox.Checked = true` in my `ListView`.

```
i.e. listview1.Items(i).Checked = True
```

For some of the items after setting up Checked property to true, I want to disable the `Checkbox` so that user cannot **uncheck** the `CheckBox`.

I am trying to figure out options on how to **disable** the `Checkboxes`, but haven't found a solution yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472172/how-do-you-disable-an-item-in-listview-control-in-net-3-5

Comment: My answer in the related post :D
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472172/how-do-you-disable-an-item-in-listview-control-in-net-3-5/22916487#22916487][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472172/how-do-you-disable-an-item-in-listview-control-in-net-3-5/22916487#22916487

Answer (score 3):

For me, this works:
Handle *ListView.ItemCheck* Event.

Use the following code there:

```
private void listView1_BeforeCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (!CheckEnabled(e)) // check somehow if clicked item is disabled
        e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a 3rd party control, [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview), but it may interest you. It supports custom check box appearances and hiding (the last two items have check boxes hidden):

[image]

To hide a check box on a specific item, simple use:

```
betterListView.Items[0].CheckBoxAppearance = BetterListViewCheckBoxAppearance.Hide;
```

Normal usage of check boxes is the same as in .NET ListView, you can have two-state or three-state check boxes or even radio buttons...